# 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' while Invoking mailmessage mailwriter method

Tags: c#-4.0, mailmessage

I am trying to create a SAVE Method for mailmessage, It is throwing the below error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Parameter count mismatch.

Below is the Overriden Method:

```
_sendMethod.Invoke(
    Message,
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
    null,
    new object[] { _mailWriter, true },
    null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The extension method dosen't supports .NET framework 4.5 above versions.
So parameter count exceptions will occur.. The Same extension method is working fine in .NET Framework 4.0 below